# Intel compiler with openCV how does it work

Tags: c++, opencv, dll, compiler-construction

I have a C# project, a CLI/C++ project which wraps a C++ project.

I have compiled openCV 3.0.0 and I'm using full static link( *.lib without *.dll files)

since I want to use Intel IPP i want to use the intel Compiler in order to compile the C++ project.

at first I tought I will have problems since the OpenCV libs aren't compiled with the Intel compiler(they are compiled with VS2012 compiler).
So just for trying I switch the toolset flag to Intel Compiler 14.0 and it worked, I can run my app... and use openCV and IPP.

Can you please explain a little bit about why is this possible? is it the same for dynamic loading(*.dll)? or if I use openCV with dynamic loading I will need to compile them with Intel Compiler?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roughly. The compiler used to generate a given machine code does not really matters (except for the quality of the code). What is important is that some conventions are respected : format of object code files, naming external objects and ABI (the way functions are called).

Comment: Can you please try to explain if it will work for dynamic loading as well?

Comment: Exactly the same... If you want code to be plugged into some other code whatever the plugging is, then you need to comply to some convention. Of course you can create your own, but for portability you always use the same on a given branch of a system.